# After upgrading to Neo4j v2.1.2, Cypher query doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Query that worked in v2.0.3

```
START n = NODE(67635)   
MATCH (n:publication)   
WHERE n.status <> 0 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[re:contains|can_use]->(e)   
WHERE (e:article) AND (e.status <> 0 AND re.status <> 0)    
WITH n, e   
ORDER BY e.created DESC 
WITH n, COLLECT(e) AS ce    
RETURN n, ce[0..10], LENGTH(ce)
```

Now, in v2.1.2 I get the following err for the same query:

```
Cannot match on a pattern containing only already bound identifiers (line 2, column 1)\n\"MATCH (n:publication)\"\n ^\n    [exception] => SyntaxException\n    [fullname] => org.neo4j.cypher.SyntaxException\n    [stacktrace] => Array\n        (\n            [0] => org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.SemanticChecker$$anonfun$check$1.apply(SemanticChecker.scala:40)\n            [1] => org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.SemanticChecker$$anonfun$check$1.apply(SemanticChecker.scala:40)\n
```

I know how to fix it, but I'd like to avoid fixing queries in the whole project if possible.
Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your Neo4j database to use an older Cypher compiler/parser, e.g. `CYPHER 2.0`

You can do that per query or globally in `neo4j.properties`

```
cypher_parser_version=CYPHER 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor this into:

```
MATCH (n:publication)   
WHERE ID(n)=67635 AND n.status <> 0 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[re:contains|can_use]->(e)   
WHERE (e:article) AND (e.status <> 0 AND re.status <> 0)    
WITH n, e   
ORDER BY e.created DESC 
WITH n, COLLECT(e) AS ce    
RETURN n, ce[0..10], LENGTH(ce)
```

Also note that matching multiple relationship types now requires a colon as prefix of each type:

```
old: OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[re:contains|can_use]->(e)   
new: OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[re:contains|:can_use]->(e)
```